# What is the purpose of Orphan Rock?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I've discovered orphan rock and can't find a quest/use for it. Is there any quest related to it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's part of the quest [Blessings of Nature](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Orphan_Rock).

> In order to cut a path through the roots of the Eldergleam Tree, Danica Pure-Spring sends the Dragonborn to Orphan Rock to collect Nettlebane, a dagger which can cut through the roots.